# homestead.app goes to Google

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I'm on OS X, I have vagrant / homestead set up. this is my homestead.yaml:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Sites
      to: /home/vagrant/Sites

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Sites/deomens/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

and here's my `/etc/hosts`:

```
192.168.10.10   homestead.app
```

but whenever I type homestead.app in, it sends me off to google straight away. I tried `vagrant provision` and also `homestead destroy` and then `homestead up` but it still does that. I tried restarting my machine, but still no luck. It feels like my computer doesn't like the hosts file.

...??

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I added http:// in front and it worked. Doesn't work without it though..

Strange.